# Can you do CSS rounded corners in IE without using images?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, rounded-corners

Is there any way to make a rounded border in IE without using images using CSS only, or any other easy way?

I have checked other questions like this on Stack Overflow, but I’m not getting an exact way.

Comment: Check out the link: http://dimox.net/cross-browser-border-radius-rounded-corners/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep as bookmark : http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/28/css3-solutions-for-internet-explorer/ ;)

For `border-radius` specifically, see http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/

Answer (score 0):

You can do on for I9 only as it supports `border-radius` css property. Otherwise it seems to be difficult without images.